# Unit test just returns 1 result of 10 cases from loop

Tags: unit-testing, assert

i am trying to get all 10 results of 10 cases from For loop. but when i run, it just returns for me the first result of the first time. any help for this condition, this is my whole code, it includes 
2 files, i have tried many times to fix it.

```
    //file BankAccount.cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Bank //just want to demo this thing, it hasn't completed
{
    namespace BankAccountNS
    {
        public class BankAccount
        {
            private double m_balance;


            public BankAccount(double balance)
            {
                m_balance = balance;
            }

            public bool getMoney(double amount) //funtion get money from account
            {

                if (amount > m_balance || amount < 0) //check money
                {
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
}


//file BankAccountTests.cs
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using Bank.BankAccountNS;

namespace BankTest
{
    [TestClass]
    public class BankAccountTests
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestEveryDebit(BankAccount Ba) //test every case from TestAll
        {
            Assert.IsTrue(Ba.getMoney(24000));
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void TestAll() //create all cases
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                BankAccount Ba = new BankAccount(23996 + i);
                TestEveryDebit(Ba);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: any help from others :(

Comment: What exactly is the issue you're having?  Also, this looks like MSTest, which doesn't allow for parameterized unit tests as far as I'm aware.  If nothing else, i would think `TestEveryDebit` should not be marked as a `[TestMethod`].  `TestAll` should continue to be marked as a `[TestMethod]` and `TestEveryDebit` should probably be private (I think)

Comment: Also, if you were to follow through on your for loop, at some point your test assert would return false, so I'm not really clear on what you're testing

Comment: @Kritner you can see, in the for loop, if it returns for me a false result, it will stop at this time. so what i need is how to keep in track the loop for all cases to ensure that it continually run.

Comment: @Kritner i just want to demo Unit testing in C#, a main trouble is how to run through all cases and display it to Test explorer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really clear on what your (attempted) loop asserts would be accomplishing, but the method `getMoney` seemingly has 2 (or 3) useful unit tests:

> Is the amount greater than the balance I have? - return false
>
> Is my account balance less than zero - return false
>
> Is my amount less than or equal too my balance? - return true

In your current setup (if it were to work) you're simply testing `getMoney` is returning true for amounts even greater than the balance - this is incorrect and does not adhere to the logic you have coded too.

I see your unit tests looking like:

```
    private double _balance = 50;
    private BankAccount _unitTestObject;

    [TestMethod]
    public void getMoney_returnsFalseWithInsufficientFunts() //create all cases
    {
        _unitTestObject = new BankAccount(_balance );
        var results = _unitTestObject.getMoney(_balance+1);

        Assert.IsFalse(results);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void getMoney_returnsFalseWhenAccountHasLessThanZero() //create all cases
    {
        _unitTestObject = new BankAccount(-1);
        var results = _unitTestObject.getMoney(1);

        Assert.IsFalse(results);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void getMoney_returnsTrueWhenAccountSufficientBalance() //create all cases
    {
        _unitTestObject = new BankAccount(_balance);
        var results = _unitTestObject.getMoney(_balance);

        Assert.IsTrue(results);
    }
```

As I stated in comments, MSTest can't do parameterized tests, and what it looks like you're attempting to do (assert specific logic 10 times) could be done like this:

```
[TestClass]
public class BankAccountTests
{

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestAll() //create all cases
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            BankAccount Ba = new BankAccount(23996 + i);
            TestEveryDebit(Ba);

        }
    }

    private void TestEveryDebit(BankAccount Ba) //test every case from TestAll
    {
        Assert.IsTrue(Ba.getMoney(24000));
    }
}
```

***But*** the test `TestAll` will always fail, because at some point in your loop, you're going to be trying to take out more `amount` than you have `balance`.

When `Assert`ing based on a loop, the "success or failure" of the test is based on the whole, not each individual assert.  So even though a few runs of your loop will "pass", the test will fail as a whole.

Comment: so what can i do to handle this error? because i want to take results of 10 cases in loop to Test explorer. can i use try catch or any way to keep in track 10 times even if result is false.

Comment: You can't, not with MSTest.  You're trying to use it in a way (which I still don't understand) that was not intended.  You can use parameterized tests in NUnit.